# I can't get the last state of an EditText

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onfocuschangelistener

I realized that the UI elements listeners are called from top down order...
(OnTouch -> OnFocusChange -> OnClick.)

So i had a setOnFocusChangeListener in the following way:

```
editTextPhoneNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                clearIfNotMatch((EditText) v, new Integer[]{12, 13});
            }
        }
    });
```

This method checks if the field was inserted correctly, if it is wrong the content of this field is deleted.

In the setOnClickListener method that where I perform the field validation it is not taking the final value of the field ... it's like it was still filled!!!

```
buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //buttonRegister.requestFocus();
                startValidation();
                if (validation.isValid()) {
                    showsNewDialog();
                }

            }
        });
```

If i click on another edittext before clicking the button the validation works.

If I click directly on the button I cannot validate correctly

Code of startValidation:

```
private void startValidation() {
        validation= new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
        validation.addValidation(editTextNumberOfSections, new FieldRequired(), getString(R.string.validation_field_required));
        validation.addValidation(editTextPhoneNumber, new FieldRequired(), getString(R.string.validation_field_required));
    }
```

Please help me!

Comment: can post code of  startValidation

Comment: I edited the question with the code